# Datasets normalization

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

I've tried to use `MinMaxScaller` (from `sklearn.preprocessing`) to normalize training data. Then created a trained file and save as 'XXX.h5'.

I attempted to create a prediction program that could read the 'XXX.h5' and use the trained model. I would need to scale the input data then inverse scale the output data.

Is there a method not to  use the training data again to scale the input data?

1. I need to read the training file again to get the scale:

```py
df=pd.read_excel('data.xls')
x=np.array(df['x'])
y=np.array(df['y'])
x_scaler=MinMaxScaler()
y_scaler=MinMaxScaler()

x=x_scaler.fit_transform(x)
y=y_scaler.fit_transform(y)
```

2. Then scale the input 'x' to make the prediction:

```py
preds= model.predict(x_scaler.transform(input_x))
```

3. Inverse the scale to get the output:

```py
preds=y_scaler.inverse_transform( preds)
```

Based on above, I will always need the training data even I don't need to train the model. Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

A possible way of doing so would be to save the parameters of the Scaler.

Sklearns MinMaxScaler has the two methods of .getparams and .setparams with which you should be able to get the parameters, save them, reload them and use them to set up the scaler.

That would need the saving and loading of an additional file, but could be preferable in case of large sample-sizes.

Comment: Thanks trikPu, the parameters I got from get_params was: {'copy': True, 'feature_range': (0, 1)}. I have no idea how to use them. But based on this, from data_min_ and data _max_ I could get the parameters I need. Then use np.savez('data.npz', x_max=x_scaler.data_max_, x_min=x_scaler.data_min_) to save them, and use np.load('data.npz') to reload them.